# Call super() with ...args

Tags: inheritance, typescript

How to call super constructor with same arguments, like current constructor call?

```
class B {
    constructor(...args) {
    }
}

class C extends B {
    constructor(...args) {
        // Here is an compile error.
        super(...args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the TypeScript compiler doesn't accept this natively. You could refactor it a bit so that the base class constructor accepts an array *or* an array of arguments:

```
class B {
    constructor(...args: string[]);
    constructor(argsArray: string[]);
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
        if(args && args.length === 1 && args[0] instanceof Array) {
            // Use args[0] as string[]
        } else {
            // Use args as string[]
        }
    }
}

class C extends B {
    constructor(...args: string[]) {
        // OK
        super(args);
    }
}
```